# Docker can't build my application with Numpy

Tags: python, docker, numpy, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to docker-compose up my flask app, but i get errors when i try to do that... I think it might be something with numpy or sklearn, but i couldn't figure it out. [error from terminal][1]Any advice can help, here is my Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3.6-alpine
    WORKDIR /code
    ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
    ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
    RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
    RUN apk add g++
    RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
        gfortran musl-dev
    RUN pip install psycopg2
    RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
    COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    EXPOSE 5000
    COPY . .
    CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

And here is an **error** from my vs code terminal, It says something abou lapack but I dont understand what I should do in Dockerfile:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-y4lyu4_s/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (164 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation != "CPython"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting Cython>=0.28.5
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.13.3
    Downloading numpy-1.13.3.zip (5.0 MB)
  Collecting scipy>=0.19.1
    Downloading scipy-1.5.4.tar.gz (25.2 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: still running...
    Installing build dependencies: still running...
    Installing build dependencies: still running...
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpjy5opf59
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-nfhvrlyl/scipy_e0c426d79aeb421b8a1f50c312717b76
      Complete output (137 lines):
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_clapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

        NOT AVAILABLE

      setup.py:462: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-4ervgef2'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])))
      Running from SciPy source directory.
      /tmp/pip-build-env-255loami/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
          Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
          the ATLAS environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      /tmp/pip-build-env-255loami/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      /tmp/pip-build-env-255loami/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel     
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-255loami/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 161, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-255loami/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 254, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-255loami/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 583, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "setup.py", line 579, in setup_package
          setup(**metadata)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-255loami/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
          config = configuration()
        File "setup.py", line 477, in configuration
          raise NotFoundError(msg)
      numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpjy5opf59 Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed 
--no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-y4lyu4_s/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Please post the _full_ output. I'm not seeing 164 lines either in your post or your image. Also please [don't post code or errors in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: @Thomas sir, I added another chunk of terminal output, hope that will clear something for you

Comment: You error comes from `requirements.txt`, but you even did not paste it.